# No, now is advertisement time. It will be back soon

Tags: grammar

He was watching TV.

There was a advertisement in the show.

"Is the show finished?" He said.

> "No, now is advertisement. It will be back soon."
>
> "No, now is advertisement time. It will be back soon."

Would they the same meaning.

We have school time, break time. Can it advertisement time?

Comment: I've only ever heard *No, it's **the ad-break*** in such contexts. But of course I'm in the UK, where the most watched (by me at least) channels are from the BBC. Which still has breaks between programs (largely consisting of "trailers" for other BBC programmes), but those wouldn't normally be called ad-breaks. I don't think the average Brit really has a name for these inter-programme gaps, but I assume people in the TV business itself do.

Comment: We wouldn't say "now is advertisement" or "now is advertisement time".  I would say "This is advertising" or "Now it is showing advertising."

Comment: I'm curious - when you say TV, do you specifically mean a TV show on a television? The reason I ask is that for that specific case, I would call the advertising "commercials" as in DoWhileNot's answer. For most other cases, such as watching a video on my phone, I would call the advertising "ads."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my part of the US, it's usually called a "commercial break," which is shortened to just "commercials."

You can have advertisement time - it technically works, however using the phrase, "now is ad-break time," or "now is commercial time" sounds a bit awkward to me, and a native speaker probably wouldn't say it that way.

If someone asked me if the show was over, usually I'd say, "No, this is just a commercial.  The show will be back soon."  So we refer to the commercial itself, or the thing being displayed and not to the time period that it's being shown in.

Comment: That's interesting. I guess I've always looked at commercials negatively, so my focus remains on the show that is being interrupted. I would answer, "No, it's (the show) at (or on) commercials."